# DriverManager.getConnection in Java by using relative path

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm making a program for someone's business in Java. 
In order to make the database connection. All i know is to use the absolute path. Which means `C:/users/documents/netbeansprojects/project/database.sqlite`

How I can use a relative path. Like `../../project/database.sqlite` or something.

I dont want to go on his computer looking what is the exact username and location to use the absolute path. Its kinda weird though.

Can somebody help me how to use a relative path in Java to my sqlite database.
So that on no matter what machine, it will anytime find connection with the database, without interfering with the java code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
getClass().getResource("../../project/database.sqlite")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick response! It's only my third program in Java :p